# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. Python import error

Tags: python, import

i keep getting this error and from what i searched, my imports are correct:

```
from .entities.entity import Session, engine, Base
```

The error is:

```
C:\Users\ArrowPlus\PycharmProjects\arrowplus\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ArrowPlus/PycharmProjects/arrowplus/backend/src/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ArrowPlus/PycharmProjects/arrowplus/backend/src/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .entities.entity import Session, engine, Base
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

My project files are depicted in this image:

[image]

Comment: have you tried just `entities.entity`

Comment: yeah i get this error: Unresolved reference 'entities'

Comment: what is your cwd for running the script

Comment: i use this file: bootstrap.sh.
which runs on C:\Users\ArrowPlus\PycharmProjects\arrowplus\backend>

Comment: You might need to do src.entities.entity then, because your cwd is backend
 
 
But more importantly.. how are you calling python in that bash file

Comment: this is the code on my bash file:
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=./src/main.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
flask run -h 127.0.0.1